# React component render Child component

Tags: reactjs

Some thing wrong with my code:

## 1 in this case header not displaying

```
import React from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router';

import CurrentUser from './../services/current-user.js';
import HeaderWithoutLogin from './header-without-login.js';
import HeaderWithLogin from './header-with-login.js';

let Header = React.createClass({
    render: () => {
        var Child = CurrentUser.isLoggedIn()
            ? HeaderWithLogin
            : HeaderWithoutLogin;
        return <div>{Child}</div>;
    }
});

export default Header;
```

## 2 in this case I got an error: "Cannot read property 'state' of undefined"

```
import React from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router';

import CurrentUser from './../services/current-user.js';
import HeaderWithoutLogin from './header-without-login.js';
import HeaderWithLogin from './header-with-login.js';

let Header = React.createClass({
    render: () => {
        if (CurrentUser.isLoggedIn()) {
            return <HeaderWithLogin/>;
        }
        return <HeaderWithoutLogin/>;
    }
});

export default Header;
```

How I need use my logic? I mean return and render different views regarding the statement

Comment: Can you elaborate on what is causing the state error, from what component the error stems and so on or post each components source code.

Comment: @limelights
createRouter.js:275 => Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined
it becasue this is undefined in the HeaderWithLogin, but why?

Comment: Can you post each components source, please?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/paveleremin/hzsnoh2h/ - Header.js
http://jsfiddle.net/paveleremin/zpe8hfyy/ - HeaderWithLogin.js

Comment: It must be an error higher up in the hierarchy, can you post full stacktrace, please?

Comment: @limelights sure, can you open https://jsbin.com/pedepa/edit?html,js,console,output in Chrome please? And you will see the error

Comment: @limelights I solved the problem, it was an issue with ES6. I user:
render: () => {}
instead of
render() {}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `render` method within `HeaderWithLogin` is not correct.

```
render: () => {}
```

will try to bind `this` to something totally different from what you're expecting, which will produce `undefined`.

Change to this and it'll work.

```
render() {}
```

or ES5 equivalent

```
render: function () {}
```

Comment: can you help me with other more simple question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32490144/react-extends-class-using-es5 ?